# React onclick Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I import `MouseEvent` from react

```
import { MouseEvent } from 'react';
```

Use `MouseEvent` in the following

```
  const closeSelectBox = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
    if (!searchOptionWrapRef.current?.contains(e.target)) {
      setOpenSelectBox(false)
    }
  };
```

I listen to my `closeSelectBox`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", closeSelectBox);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", closeSelectBox);
    };
  }, [])
```

`searchOptionWrapRef` is a `div`

```
const searchOptionWrapRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

<div ref={searchOptionWrapRef}/>
```

But I get the following error

```
Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 43 more.
```

How do I resolve this type error without using `any` in place of `MouseEvent`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The event interfaces exported by React are for React event handler props, not `addEventListener` handlers. For those, *don't* import `MouseEvent` from React and you'll get the DOM global interface for it instead, which works with `addEventListener`. And yes, it's confusing. :-)

But the second issue (which actually may be your main issue) is that the DOM global `MouseEvent` defines `target` as an `EventTarget`, not as a `Node`. In your case, it'll always be a `Node` (specifically, an `Element`), but that's how the DOM type is defined. To deal with that, you have at least two choices:

#### Purist

You could go really purist (I do) and use a type assertion function to assert that `target` is a `Node`:

```typescript
// In a utility library:
function assertIsNode(e: EventTarget | null): asserts e is Node {
    if (!e || !("nodeType" in e)) {
        throw new Error(`Node expected`);
    }
}

// And then in your component:
const closeSelectBox = ({target}: MouseEvent): void => {
    assertIsNode(target);
    if (!searchOptionWrapRef.current?.contains(target)) {
        setOpenSelectBox(false);
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSyZcAvnGVBCHAERSoacDcAKEFl8AOwzAIYuCkLFYASUIA5CABMkACiQAuOCQBuSMTAAqKKAHMk8AD5wx+ADbOAlPrkKYhOEjjAvmqauIJw4QEMWgCE-nYO0VqcYhpIZgCeYEicATJIbm6hEcVwMAAWbADujkjVJFBsUFoABsH+SAAeWRhI6s1uQsWMgsOCaNKE8CQdKODO-gC8cFqFCwB8RRHjYpNwxJZoZQDyYDBSYgDqUChg9HBLtPQAPAASZgCyADIAIsCGJPMQCYYGstE5XAMwlsJvA0M4IMQAMpIeYYABCEA692WOBglhsMEY+neEFoRmBHjghggwHU9w2OChJVk8iQSlUqS0eOstkhzPCwCi0X2UEOJzO0iuN3oADo0PgGsCAPxy6R44A7Ln43mFRn8koAegNe1sJxMyNRMAxHS0ZBQzmIbiZJWGQyEzrJFCoMC0K3pm2Z6gg8qBphlKHU6nJpk+gRgJjZSThwDQAGtONg4QikBbvda+fyeDAFTI-esA-q4EGQ8CZTwQBBjNGYLHJgmmpxk2mM3As0iUXnMQXmYxBhFGNgANoAXUhzqLJbgT3UfzgPDICxwIrFp3OUtuSDIjANayEo8EQA)

#### Concise and Pragmatic

You **know** that `target` is a `Node` and isn't `null`, so you could use a type assertion (`target as Node`):

```typescript
const closeSelectBox = ({target}: MouseEvent): void => {
    if (!searchOptionWrapRef.current?.contains(target as Node)) {
        setOpenSelectBox(false);
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSyZcAvnGVBCHAERSoacDcAKEFoIAO0LwSADxTgANkjgBeOAAoAlCoB8uQXANxRE+MRRQ0ACwDyYGMHEB1KCjD0VBYvQA8ACQAqALIAMgAiwABuJIogSGIw2mpi+PLyGkKGRuKSRvIQxADKSIoYAEIQ0h5qODDmAOZIMIwAXHCBELQkEXEwGq0REMAAJjp6mZnADGoAhGYWNnYOYs6u9AB0aPhQPPEA-BvitcASarVQDfAohHAAchBDSBpaOPrjbwD073DEMLZxRSUYOVpGoyCh5MR0q83oxoUwhHDOhQqDA1JpRi83gYhhBNrF4msUEMhl0esFgJI4kgoGpOGh5MA0ABrTjYen5JAAlHAqFYuA8GBbMTqLTKXSYvmGHF4nprHggCDdUnxcmUsTU2n0xkstl5QrFbkVXlYxgZQyMbAAbQAulC4QKhXBvENIvykGRlDg5lZbPYnC43O7GO9tEJTYIgA)

I don't like type assertions that aren't checked at runtime (which is what a type assertion function like `assertIsNode` does), so I'd probably go with the first approach. But in limited situations where you're sure about it, you might consider one.

Comment: What is the DOM global interface? Should I just use `any` in place of `MouseEvent`?

Comment: @dev_el - That DOM global interface is global, you don't import it from anywhere (that I know of). Don't use `any` if you want type safety. :-) But I was doing a TypeScript playground example and it looks like there's a second problem. I'm working on that now...

Comment: @dev_el =-Done now, sorry about that. I jumped to the conclusion that it was *just* the choice of event interface that was the problem, but it wasn't just that.

Answer (score 6):

You can assert that the instance is of `Element` or `HTMLElement` using [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). This solution solves both runtime and compile time checking in a minimal way without causing exceptions.

```
const closeSelectBox = (e: MouseEvent): void => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLElement && !searchOptionWrapRef.current?.contains(e.target)) {
    setOpenSelectBox(false)
  }
};
```

Comment: I like `instanceof` here, however, I'd recommend using `Node` instead of `Element` because that's the type `contains()` is expecting. `HTMLElement` also doesn't apply to  inline SVG, which could prevent outside click detection if they click an icon, for example.

Answer (score 3):

This solve in my use case. I assert to typescript that "target" is of Node type.

```
function handleOutsideClickModal({ target }: MouseEvent) {
    if (!sidebar.current?.contains(target as Node)) {
        setOpenModal(!openModal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
 if(e.target instanceof Node) { // check the condition
    if (ref.current?.contains(e.target)) { // won't give error
        // do code here
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

### A couple of points to covert the whole issue:

1. setup TypeScript to support the browser DOM JS APIs
2. React events vs browser events

### TypeScript Setup

TypeScript by default doesn't know where you're going to run your code.

It can be in the browser or it can be in Node.js, you have to tell.

So, to support the browser DOM JS APIs which includes the browser events you have to edit `tsconfig.json` > `compilerOptions` and add the `dom` library. (see the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)).

```
# tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom"],
        .
        .
        .
    },
}
```

### React events vs Browser events

As said in other answers, the React events are meant for React and *are not compatible with the browser DOM JS APIs, which is used by `addEventListener`*.

Just to clarify, `import { MouseEvent } from 'react';` take the definition from [`@types/react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L1351) and *won't use the Browser DOM JS APIs*.

To support the Browser DOM JS APIs you'll need to use the TypeScript `lib: [dom]` within the config, as per the explanation.

If you need the two events together, you can use `import { MouseEvent as RMouseEvent} from 'react';`. In this way `MouseEvent` will be attached to the Browser DOM and `RMouseEvent` for React.

Or else, you could extract your `useEffect` in a custom hook within a different file. In this way, the custom hook will use the Browser DOM and your main component will use the React Event.

### About the Code

```
// No import { MouseEvent} from 'react';
// or import { MouseEvent as RMouseEvent} from 'react';
// This need lib: [dom] in tsconfig

const isParentChild = 
        (parent: HTMLElement, child: Node | null) => 
            parent.contains(child);

useEffect(() => {
    const closeSelectBox = 
        (e: MouseEvent) => 
            !isParentChild(searchOptionWrapRef.current as HTMLElement, e.target as Node)
                && setOpenSelectBox(false);

    if (searchOptionWrapRef == null || searchOptionWrapRef.current == null) {
        return;
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", closeSelectBox);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", closeSelectBox);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: I wrote a [post](https://adropincalm.com/blog/check-focus-within-in-javascript-and-react/) that cover the whole topic in case you want to dig further